# Maximum clique of a digraph under some edge constraints

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Assume there are $2k+1$ nodes. For any group of $k$ nodes, at least one node has to receive one edge from each of the remaining $k+1$ nodes. If this is true for any group of $k$ nodes among $2k+1$ nodes, what is the smallest maximum clique of this digraph?

I can't really figure out how to approach this.

Can anyone help me with other materials or problems similar to mine so that I can look for some inspiration?

Comment: Have you tried to find a triangle ($K_3$) in such a graph? Have you tried using bipartite graphs to construct such a graph without $K_4$? Include your answers to these questions in your text. You will definitely get an answer to your question.

Comment: Can you add that into the question, like dealing with the case of $k = 3$?

Comment: Unfortunately, $k=3$ is the part where my confusion starts. My guess is that the answer is $K_k$ tho... it works for $k=1,2$

Comment: @JJJ, No. It doesn't work already for $k=1$.

Answer (score 3):

> Let in a simple graph $G=(V,E)$ with $2k+1$ vertices, each subset $X\subset V$
> with $|X|=k$ contains at least one vertex adjacent to each vertex
> of the set $V\setminus X$.

Prove that $G$ contains $K_{k+2}$.

Let $K_s$ be a maximal complete subgraph of $G$ and $s\leq k+1$. Let $U$ be the vertex set of $K_s$. Since $|V\setminus U|\geq k$, $V\setminus U$ contains a vertex $u$ which is adjacent to all vertices from $U$. But then $K_s+u=K_{s+1}$. Contradiction.

Let now be a graph $G=K_{k+1}\cup O_{k}$ in which $O_k$ has $k$ vertices and no edges and every vertex of $O_k$ is connected to every vertex of the graph $K_{k+1}$. The described operation on the graphs $K_{k+1}$ and $O_k$ is called the *disjoint union* of graphs (or the *graph sum*) and is denoted by $K_{k+1}+O_k$.

Check that the graph $G$ satisfies our condition, contains $K_{k+2}$, and does not contain $K_{k+3}$.

**Remark.**
This is my answer for the simple graphs that were the subject of the first version of the question.

Comment: @JJJ, It seems like the goalposts have moved since I answered. Tricky to keep up with changing questions! This seems unacceptable to me. It would be correct to ask a new question about directed graphs.

Comment: I would write here $K_{k + 1} + O_k$ rather than $K_{k + 1} \cup O_k$, because in graph theory $G \cup H$ is the [disjoint union of graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphUnion.html), while $G + H = \overline{\overline{G} \cup \overline{H}}$ is the [join of graphs](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphJoin.html) $G$ and $H$, which is exactly what you describe

Comment: @Smylic Thanks a lot for your comment. I completely agree with you. I am going to add this to my answer.